# Unable to transmit/inject 802.11 packets using Scapy

Tags: python, ubuntu, wifi, scapy

I'm trying to transmit a data frame (using scapy in ubuntu 18.04) between my desktop and laptop. I would like the MSDU to just be some raw data and not an upper layer frame. For whatever reason I am unable to detect transmitted packets between the devices.

Both devices are set in monitor mode and are connected to the same frequency/channel. For example, my desktop has wireless interface *wlp4s0* which I set up as follows:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 down
sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up
sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 channel n
```

When I check `iw dev` or `iwconfig` I can see that both wireless interfaces are in monitor mode and at the same frequency with a non-zero tx-power.

I have no problems sniffing the channel using scapy with the following code:

```
sniff(iface = "wlp4s0", prn = output)
```

Where prn just prints out the summary of any packet.

When I try to transmit I use the following code on one device:

```
    header = Dot11(
        addr1 = "00:16:ea:12:34:56",
        addr2 = "00:16:ea:12:34:56",
        addr3 = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
        type = 2,
        subtype = 0,
        FCfield = 0)

    data = "testtesttesttest"
    packet = header / data
    sendp(data, iface= "wlp4s0", loop = 1, inter = 0.100)
```

Despite the transmitting device stating the packet has been transmitted, the other devices cannot see any of the packets while sniffing the channel. Similarly, while using 'ifconfig' the *tx_count* for the interface is not increasing.

I've tried switching roles on both devices, but have also had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I took a look at the output packet in wireshark and it shows the protocol as LLC and not 802.11. Perhaps this has something to do with why transmission is not occuring.

Comment: Resolved on https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1767

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are sending packets to yourself.
addr1 is for the receiver.
addr2 is for the sender.